# Flatten an array of objects and get unique keys and values by a repeated date with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I've been playing around with Lodash and not getting close to a solution that doesn't involve a lot of extra looping and overhead.

```
data: [
    {
      name: "FirstResult", values: [
        {
          value: { NameCount: 1, OtherCount: 1 },
          date: 2019-05-15T07:00:00+0000
        },
        {
          value: { NameCount: 1 },
          date: 2019-05-16T07:00:00+0000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "SecondResult",
      values: [
        {
          value: { NameCount: 1 },
          date: 2019-05-15T07:00:00+0000
        },
        {
          value: { BuyCount: 2, SellCount: 1 },
          date: 2019-05-16T07:00:00+0000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I'd like to flatten this and have it combined and aggregated by using the date as the key returning some configuration like:

```
[ 
  { date: 2019-05-15T07:00:00+0000, values: { NameCount: 2, OtherCount: 1 } },
  { date: 2019-05-16T07:00:00+0000, values: { NameCount: 1, BuyCount: 2, SellCount: 1 } }
]
```

Or even just a flat object array is fine like:

```
[ 
  { date: 2019-05-15T07:00:00+0000, NameCount: 2, OtherCount: 1 },
  { date: 2019-05-16T07:00:00+0000, NameCount: 1, BuyCount: 2, SellCount: 1 }
]
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this with either a Lodash or Vanilla solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lodash's chain to flatten, group by the date, and then map and merge each group to a single object:

```js
const fn = data => _(data)
  .flatMap('values') // flatten to array of objects
  .groupBy(o => o.date.toISOString()) // group by the iso representation 
  .map(group => { // map the groups by merging, and converting to require format
    const { date, value } = _.mergeWith({}, ...group, (objValue, srcValue) =>
      _.isNumber(objValue) ? objValue + srcValue : undefined // combine numeric values
    )
    
    return {
      date,
      ...value,
    }
  })
  .value()

const data = [{"name":"FirstResult","values":[{"value":{"NameCount":1,"OtherCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-15T07:00:00.000Z")},{"value":{"NameCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-16T07:00:00.000Z")}]},{"name":"SecondResult","values":[{"value":{"NameCount":1},"date":new Date("2019-05-15T07:00:00.000Z")},{"value":{"BuyCount":2,"SellCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-16T07:00:00.000Z")}]}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Or you can use `_.flow()` to generate the function ([I'm using lodash/fp here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide)):

```js
const { flow, flatMap, groupBy, map, mergeAllWith, cond, isNumber, add } = _

const fn = flow(
  flatMap('values'), // flatten to array of objects
  groupBy(o => o.date.toISOString()), // group by the iso representation
  map(mergeAllWith(cond([[isNumber, add]]))), // combine numeric values
  map(({ date, value }) => ({ date, ...value })) // format the objects
)

const data = [{"name":"FirstResult","values":[{"value":{"NameCount":1,"OtherCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-15T07:00:00.000Z")},{"value":{"NameCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-16T07:00:00.000Z")}]},{"name":"SecondResult","values":[{"value":{"NameCount":1},"date":new Date("2019-05-15T07:00:00.000Z")},{"value":{"BuyCount":2,"SellCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-16T07:00:00.000Z")}]}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Here are the references to mergeWith and flow in case someone is wondering they do:

mergeWith: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith
flow: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow

Comment: Awesome solutions, exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure **ES6** solution based on [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for the object keys:

```js
const data = [{"name":"FirstResult","values":[{"value":{"NameCount":1,"OtherCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-15T07:00:00.000Z")},{"value":{"NameCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-16T07:00:00.000Z")}]},{"name":"SecondResult","values":[{"value":{"NameCount":1},"date":new Date("2019-05-15T07:00:00.000Z")},{"value":{"BuyCount":2,"SellCount":1},"date": new Date("2019-05-16T07:00:00.000Z")}]}]

let result = data.reduce((r, { values }) => {
  values.forEach(({ value, date }) => {
    let keys = Object.keys(value), d = date.toISOString()
    r[d] = r[d] || Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(x => ({ date: d, [x]: 0 })))
    keys.forEach(k => r[d][k] = (r[d][k] || 0) + value[k])
  })
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

The main idea is to get the keys of the value object white iterating and compose an object with them while grouping by the date. Then last `forEach` just sums each result object value.